# data binding scope in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I am confused with the behavior of my code

```
<body>
      <h1>Sample Application</h1>

      <div ng-app = "" ng-init = "countries = [{locale:'en-US',name:'United States'}, {locale:'en-GB',name:'United Kingdom'}, {locale:'en-FR',name:'France'}]"> 
         <p>Enter your Name: <input type = "text" id="outer" ng-model = "name"></p>
         <p>Hello <span ng-bind = "name"></span>!</p>
         <p>List of Countries with locale:</p>

         <ol>
            <li ng-repeat = "country in countries">
               {{ 'Country: ' + country.name + ', Locale: ' + country.locale }}
               <p>Enter your Name: <input type = "text" id="{{country.name}}_inner" ng-model = "name"></p>
               <p>Hello <span ng-bind = "name"></span>!</p>
            </li>
         </ol>
      </div>

      <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

   </body>
```

so the problem is when i enter some value in textbox with `id="outer"` the value inside the textbox reflects on all the textboxs but if i try to enter something in the subsequent text boxs the value reflects just in the immediate paragraph tag.

I was wondering if anyone can explain me what exactly is going on here ?
why not the value entered in every textbox is coming everywhere ?

and why the value entered in the ng-repeat tag elements is available locally only ?

and why not changing the value in the textbox with `id="outer"` later on does not change the value in the already edited ng-repeat textboxs ?

[JS fiddle of the above code](https://jsfiddle.net/3dz8d2c6/)

Thanks in anticipation !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, when you are first inputting values into `id="outer"`, you are populating parent `'name' model`, and that same model is used in your ng-repeat, because  `'name' models` in your `ng-repeat` are not yet initialized. That's why after you are inputting values in your other textboxes - name models are initialized for each of the items in `'countries'`.

Therefore, if you would like for example to modify the name model of your parent, you would do like this:

```
<li ng-repeat = "country in countries">
               {{ 'Country: ' + country.name + ', Locale: ' + country.locale }}
               <p>Enter your Name: <input type = "text" id="{{country.name}}_inner" ng-model = "$parent.name"></p>
               <p>Hello <span ng-bind = "name"></span>!</p>
            </li>
```

That way when you will be inputting in any of the inputs - you would be modifying the same `'name' model.`

Comment: I would suggest adding a function the parent scope which modifies the parents value rather than using the $parent selector as the use of $parent can cause some instability in more complex applications. Nothing wrong with this suggestion just good practice :D

Comment: thanks for the explanation but if i want the 'name' models in my ng-repeat does not get affected by editing the parent- 'name' model ? how can i achieve that. any idea ?

Comment: In your example, you can achieve that simply by changing the ng-model from "name" to, for example: "countryName", like so:

 `<p>Enter your Name: <input type = "text" id="{{country.name}}_inner" ng-model = "countryName"></p>`

Answer (score 0):

It's only understand how it works in Angularjs.

The `ngModel` directive binds an input, select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.

The `ngBind` attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the text content when the value of that expression changes.

So in your input `outer` you set `ng-model` with `name`, and `name` is set in all your `ng-bind` and `ng-model`, that's why you see the value everywhere.